# Generating dynamic text box using drop down

Tags: javascript

Hello I am a newbie to java script i wrote code to generate one text box by selecting a drop down option 1 and and two text boxes by selecting a drop down 2 but i am getting the value in the text box like select_0 and select_ 1 .... Here is my code

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function()
        {
            var select = document.getElementById("select");
            var texts = document.getElementById("texts");
            select.onchange = function()
            {
                var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
                texts.innerHTML = "";
                for(i=0; i < val; i++)
                {
                    texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="t_' + i + '" value="select_' + i + '" /></div>';
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="connection.php">
Question:<br>
<textarea name="question" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<select id="select" size="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<div id="texts"></div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly suggest me not to get the value inside the text box.I dont know where i went wrong.Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/JgWrf/

Comment: Hello jack where should i keep the value then??

Comment: @Ananth i am getting the same output i dont want the value to be inside the text box rather i want that value out side i am not getting how to do that .Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShashankCool updated my answer so before the textbox it shows select_1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'value' attribute of a text input *is* the text in the text box. If you don't want that to be displayed in the text box, simply do the following:

```
    texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="t_' + i + '" /></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way than using innerHTML but right now I'm feeling lazy. Just remove the value= part when you set the text input and I've set the innerHTML outside the loop because setting innerHTML is kind of expensive (processing) and should not be used in a loop.

```
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        var texts = document.getElementById("texts");
        select.onchange = function()
        {
            var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value,
            //set the innerHTML one time using ret (Array)
            ret=[];
            texts.innerHTML = "";
            for(i=0; i < val; i++)
            {
                // do not set value property:
                ret.push('select_' + i + ': <div><input type="text" name="t_' 
                  + i + '"/></div>');
            }
            // set innerHTML here
            texts.innerHTML = ret.join("");
        }
    }
```